# How to choose fid- versus kred-?

Tags: word-difference

I am profoundly confused by these two roots. Why should I not **kred**i someone who is not **fid**inda, why do people **fid**as in God, but things are ne**kred**eblaj? What question should I pose in my mind when deciding which root to use in a word I'm going to say? Thank you!

**Update:** Turns out I was wrong about the phrase *kredi je Dio*, I don't know why I thought it was *fidi*. That certainly added needlessly to the confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary meaning of *kredi* is *believe* (a statement). The primary meaning of *fidi* is *trust* (a person). So the original distinction is between putting faith in an idea, or in a person.

For example, *kredi je Dio* is to believe in God, i.e. to believe the statement "God exists." *Fidi Dion* is to trust God.

Secondary meanings allow you to *kredi al persono, al viaj okuloj* (to believe a person, i.e. to believe the statements of a person; to believe your eyes) and to *fidi la vorton, la honestecon, la kapablojn de iu* (to trust the word, the honesty, the abilities of a person).

Thus, in both these meanings, the difference is that ***kredi* refers to the acceptance of specific statements or ideas, whereas *fidi* refers to a more general trust.**

Answer (score 3):

*Kredo* has to do with things that you hold to be true. *Fido* has to do with trust or confidence in something. It can also mean a "belief based on religion."

On this last point, I will call your attention to the following clarifying note from PIV:

> En tiuj ekzemploj **fido** aspektas kiel sinonimo de **kredo**. Sed la jena ekzemplo montras la diferencon: *ankaŭ la diablo kredas je Dio, sed mankas al li la ĝusta fido*

Answer (score 1):

- **Fido** = Trust
- **Kredo** = Belief

**Mi kredas je Dio** = I believe in God (I believe that she exists)

**Mi fidas je Dio** = I trust in God (I trust what she says)